# Ошибка "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST"

Tags: mysql, node.js

Связка NODEJS+MySQL. Подцепляюсь к базе, создаю временную таблицу, заливаю в нее данные. Какое то время спустя коннекция падает. Ошибка "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST". Вешаю обработчик на ошибку:

```
connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('db error query_1', err);
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
        db.connect();
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
};
```

Но пересоздание коннекции приводит к уничтожению временной таблицы. Есть ли решение проблемы?

Comment: Попробуй добавить в строку подключения параметр Keepalive. Как показано [тут](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/keep-tcp-sockets-alive/).

Comment: Не помогло. Еще иногда EventEmitter выбрасывает такое же сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автор либы `mysql` явно [рекомендует](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1353#issuecomment-185889588) не использовать долгоживущие коннекты. Вместо этого лучше использовать пул коннектов https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections.

Мне кажется, у вас архитектурная проблема скорее всего. Если вам нужны таблицы, которые живут долго и между коннектами, не используйте временные таблицы.

Comment: Пул коннекций вроде помог, спасибо. Но теперь валится ошибка "error: handshake inactivity timeout". Увеличил таймаут  "connectTimeout: 1000000". Ошибка не исчезла.